# "IndexError: tuple index out of range" this occured while predicting the model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, python-3.10

I had created a simple fruit classification model and was predicting some data to see if the model was working as expected but when I ran it this error occured.

```
tf.keras.models.load_model("model.h5")
new_data = "new/"
predictions = model.predict(new_data)
print(predictions)
```

Here is the code and below is the full error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-249d0270d991> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 tf.keras.models.load_model("model.h5")
      2 new_data = "new/"
----> 3 predictions = model.predict(new_data)
      4 print(predictions)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    955       else:
    956         if self._v2_behavior:
--> 957           return self._dims[key]
    958         else:
    959           return self.dims[key]

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

How can I resolve it?

I haven't yet tried anything as this is the first time I encountered the error. For context, I am working on Google Colab. Also my model trained on 32 by 32 images so do I need to preprocess the images before running and is this the reason model isn't predicting?

Comment: What do you have in `new_data`? What is the dimension of `new_data` and your training data?